# snakemake only runs the first rule not all

Tags: workflow, rules, snakemake

My snakefile looks like this.

```
rule do00_download_step01_download_:
    input:
        
    output:
        "data/00_download/scores.pqt"
    run:
        from lib.do00_download import do00_download_step01_download_
        do00_download_step01_download_()
rule do00_download_step02_get_the_mean_:
    input:
        "data/00_download/scores.pqt"
    output:
        "data/00_download/cleaned.pqt"
    run:
        from lib.do00_download import do00_download_step02_get_the_mean_
        do00_download_step02_get_the_mean_()
rule do01_corr_step01_correlate:
    input:
        "data/00_download/cleaned.pqt"
    output:
        "data/01_corr/corr.pqt"
    run:
        from lib.do01_corr import do01_corr_step01_correlate
        do01_corr_step01_correlate()
rule do95_plot_step01_correlations:
    input:
        "data/01_corr/corr.pqt"
    output:
        "plot/heatmap.png"
    run:
        from lib.do95_plot import do95_plot_step01_correlations
        do95_plot_step01_correlations()
rule do95_plot_step02_plot_dist:
    input:
        "data/00_download/cleaned.pqt"
    output:
        "plot/dist.png"
    run:
        from lib.do95_plot import do95_plot_step02_plot_dist
        do95_plot_step02_plot_dist()
rule do99_figures_step01_make_figure:
    input:
        "plot/dist.png"
        "plot/heatmap.png"
    output:
        "figs/fig01.svg"
    run:
        from lib.do99_figures import do99_figures_step01_make_figure
        do99_figures_step01_make_figure()
rule all:
    input:
        "figs/fig01.svg"
```

I have arranged the rules in a sequential manner, hoping that this will make sure all the steps will be run in that order. However, when I run `snakemake`, it only runs the first rule and then it exits.

I have individually checked all the steps (functions that I import) if they work well, the paths of the input and output files. Everything looks ok. So I am guessing that the issue is with how I formatted the snakefile. I am new to `snakemake` (beginer-level). So it would be very helpful if somebody points out how I should fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the intended behavior. Here's a relevalent section from [the docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v3.10.0/tutorial/basics.html#step-7-adding-a-target-rule):

> Moreover, if no target is given at the command line, Snakemake will define the first rule of the Snakefile as the target. Hence, it is best practice to have a rule `all` at the top of the workflow which has all typically desired target files as input files.
> The output of the first rule is assumed to be the target.

If you move the `rule all:` to the top of your Snakefile, it should work as expected.

Comment: Hm, I missed that in the docs. Thanks for pointing it out!
Yes, it seems that `rule all` was the issue. I put it at the top and now the other rules are running.

Comment: But for some reason, to have the `rulegraph` that I intended to have, I had to add-in two more inputs in the `rule all`:   "plot/dist.png" and "plot/heatmap.png" in addition to "figs/fig01.svg". I don't understand why so. How to decide which file should be included in the inputs of `rule all`?

Comment: @Ramirez snakemake looks at the first rule (conventionally named `all`) to determine what the final output of the pipeline is going to be. Then it walks backwards to establish which files are needed to create such final output. If `plot/dist.png` is not in rule `all` and it's not necessary to generate the final output, then the rule creating `plot/dist.png` is not executed. This is all a bit counter-intuitive but once you get used to it, it's a useful behaviour.